# Error trying to plot a simple function in python

Tags: python, function, numpy, plot, integration

ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I get a different error depending on the integration method. The function works correctly when given a single value.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np


def mass_enc(R):
    def int(r): return r**2 * r
    return sp.integrate.quad(int, 0, R)

print(mass_enc(10))

t1 = np.arange(0.1, 5.0, 0.1)
plt.plot(t1, mass_enc(t1))
```

Comment: Some comments: If you're asking about plotting in matplotlib, use the respective tag. Since the error here, does not relate to plotting, remove the plotting part. If you are reporting an error, report also where it occurs and in which file (in this case it would be numpy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling `sp.integrate.quad` with an array as argument. While some functions actually allow that, `quad` does not. So you need to provide each value of `R` individually. This can be done by `map(function, iterable)`. So here is how you can do it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy as sp
import numpy as np

def inte(r): 
    return r**2 * r

def mass_enc(R):
    return sp.integrate.quad(inte, 0, R)[0]

print(mass_enc(10))

t1 = np.arange(0.1, 5.0, 0.1)
m = map( mass_enc, t1)
plt.plot(t1, m)
plt.show()
```

Mind, that you should **never** call any object in python `int`, since `int` is a basic type in python and doing that can cause a lot of trouble.

Comment: Thanks for your response. This then gives me ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension. Seems very strange

Comment: Again, where does the error occur? It may be that you're using an older version of matplotlib, which cannot handle a list of tuples. Try to modify the `mass_enc` function such as I did in the code above, putting `[0]` behind the `quad()` call.